# Changing citation format complicated by punctuation

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, revtex

I have a document which was originally written with a footnote based citation format in mind.  As a result the citations generally follow punctuation as in `This is a test sentence.\cite{Someone:2018}`  However, I'm now preparing pieces of that document for publication in an APS journal which makes use of a inline (bracket) citation style and thus the citations should proceed the punctuation.  Is there some LaTeX trickery that can be done to accomplish this, or do I have to manually edit the source file.

MWE with citations in "wrong" place:

```
\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bli74,
  author = {Blinder, Alan S.},
  year = {1974},
  title = {The economics of brushing teeth},
  journal = {Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {82},
  number = {4},
  pages = {887--891},
}
@book{Kop04,
  author = {Kopka, Helmut and Daly, Patrick W.},
  year = {2004},
  title = {Guide to \LaTeX},
  edition = {4},
  address = {Boston},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This is a test sentence.\cite{Bli74}  This is another, slightly more complicated,\cite{Kop04} test sentence.

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good question! IMHO, however, the time it would take for you to find this trickery is very likely way beyond than that of a CTRL+F search of `\cite` followed by manual adjustments.

Comment: This would be quite tricky. While LaTeX can look forward easily looking back is hard. So `\cite` can't move the punctuation. So I guess it would have to be the other way round: The `.` has to move the `\cite`. This would probably involve making the `.` active, getting it to grab the entire following `\cite{...}` seems very complicated. On the other hand, a short search for `.\cite` and `,\cite` seems doable. If you have a RegExp you might be able to rack up a fully automatic search-and-replace.

Comment: BTW: This is the reason why `biblatex` always wants you to write `\autocite{foo}.` and allows you to activate an option to move the punctuation around. I think a few other packages can do similar things.

Comment: Hindsight is 20/20.  If I have to deal with making punctuation active, then I guess I’ll bite the bullet and work on the search-and-replace process.